# Button handling (pseudocode/c)

Tags: c, button, pseudocode

I have a button, and I want it to react according to the actions of the user.
Here it is:

[image]

You can see that it has 4 different states. A first one is when no perticular action is performed (`NONE`), a second one is when the mouse pointer hovers the button (`HOVER`), a third one when the mouse is currently clicking on the button (`ONCLICK`), and the last one when the button has been clicked (`SELECTED`).

Even if we don't care that much, the button map is as following:

[image]

These states are presenting as an enum:

```
enum button_states  { NONE, HOVER, ONCLICK, SELECTED, BSTATE_LAST };
```

Now I tried some code to change the state of the button, code which is executed in an infinite loop. I have a variable `prevState` that hold the state before the last click, and a variable `previouslyClicked` that worth 1 if the click was active last loop iteration and worth 0 else.

```
if (CursorIsOnTheButton())  {
    if (LeftClickIsActive())    {
        if (actualState != ONCLICK)
            prevState = actualState ;
        previouslyClicked = 1;
        actualState = ONCLICK;
    }
    else if (prevState == SELECTED && previouslyClicked) {
        actualState = HOVER;
        prevState = NONE;
        previouslyClicked = 0;
    }
    else if (prevState == HOVER && previouslyClicked)   {
        actualState = SELECTED;
        prevState = NONE;
        previouslyClicked = 0;
    }
    else
        actualState  = HOVER;
}
else if (actualState != SELECTED)
    actualState = NONE;
```

It works fine except for the SELECTED state: the button never goes into that state.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe because `previouslyClicked` is set in one branch and then checked in another, mutually exclusive branch? The `LeftClickIsActive()` block should probably be extended to include the cases "hover + click -> selected" and "hover + selected -> hover".

Comment: With your method the results are at the total opposite: there is only the state SELECTED that works fine. ^^' I'll try to search following that way.

Comment: In the first else... "If I have something selected and I hover the mouse over it, it is no longer selected"... it that what you meant?

Comment: @vmp I think that would only happen if the user clicked on a different button.

Comment: lets suppose its just one button, if you click it.. it switches between selected and not selected(any other), is that your plan?

Comment: Radio buttons only looked like that on radios 30 years ago.

Comment: Often, button event handling is done using an event handling callback.  Each button will have its own callback (event handler) to handle one of several possible events: eg EVENT_COMMIT, EVENT_LEFT_CLICK, EVENT_VAL_CHANGED, etc.  (actual events change from environment to environment).  In your scenario, it looks like you really want a single button, and to handle 1 of several possible events. (thus your infinite loop)

Comment: @vmp In fact I have 2 others buttons, and I want all of them to be radiobuttons. But I thought it was pointless and heavy to add them in the presented code.

Comment: @ryyker, yes but no, I don't have any form api nor api with callbacks, ima trying to display that button thingy with SDL.

Comment: Hum... does the button display change while on hover?

Comment: hum... but if you clicked a button that was already selected, should it unselect? I was thinking this way til you said radio buttons... a radio button only unselects if you select another one...

Comment: @vmp nope, but if you click on another of the buttons present on the screen, it should unselect. I didn't implemented that yet.

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on vmp answer and all of your great help, I solved that problem.

I used vmp's variables `actualSelected` and `beingClicked`, but not as boolean, to store the ID of both selected and clicked buttons.

Let me explain, I think I didn't left enough informations to you to solve this thing. I've not only one button but an array of them, `buttons[NBUTTONS]` is their states, and they should act exactly like radiobuttons.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NBUTTONS; i++)  {
    if (IsMouseOnButton(button[i])  {
        if (LeftClickIsActive())    {
            beingClicked = i;
            buttons[i] = ONCLICK;
        }
        else if (beingClicked == i) {
            actualSelected = i;
            beingClicked = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < NBUTTONS; j++)
                buttons[i] = NONE;
            buttons[i] = SELECTED;
        }
        else if (actualSelected != i)   {
            buttons[i] = HOVER;
        }
    }
    else if (selected != i)
        buttons[i] = NONE;
}
```

Comment: look at the edt on my solution

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written to exclude SELECTED from ever being used in either block:

```
if (CursorIsOnTheButton())  {
    if (LeftClickIsActive())    {

        //if execution flow ever goes into this section...
        //(i.e. if SELECTED is set here, because you are in this block, it cannot be recognized by the 
        //else if block, because it can only go in there if it did NOT go into this one.)
    }
}
//...it will never go into the else if
else if (actualState != SELECTED)
    actualState = NONE;
```

Modify your code to include the SELECTED state in the same block as other states.

Would adding this code section to the ***if*** block:

```
else if (actualState == SELECTED)   {

    //do something 
}
```

Solve the problem?

Comment: The code never goes there by design: The last branch, which you have marked, is for dealing with the button when the mouse is outside. It should then either be in unselected, non-hover mode (`NONE`) or in the selected mode. The logic is somewhat confusing, because there is no hovering state for the depressed/selected button, only for the unselected one. (The code is called repeatedly to check for button changes, so it will eventually get there.)

Comment: This last `else if` is just here to deselect the button if the mouse isn't over it. Except if the button is selected, the state should switch to none to get the base unselected and unhovered button. Sorry if it's unclear. :s

Comment: @MOehm - There would still need to be a section inside the `if` section that is specific to handling the SELECTED case though, if I am even close to understanding the logic.

Comment: @ryyker: I think when the button was selected, it just stays selected. The control flow is not easy to understand, and I'm not sure whether I got it, either.

Comment: @M Oehm I think you got it it should stay selected.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this... and whenever you mark something to selected you call it passing the recent selected buttong as the 3rd parameter

```
void ClearOthers("Array of buttons" buttons[], int amountOfButtons, int selected)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < amountOfButtons; i++)
         if(i != selected)
             button[i].State = NONE
}
```

I think you can simplify your problem...

Use 2 booleans, the actualState starts as false (not selecteded)

A button is either selected or not...

If you click it  (and stop the click with mouse over it still) then it changes to selected

Any animation you want to do... you just need to use the 4 possible combinations of those booleans...

```
if (CursorIsOnTheButton())  
{

   if (LeftClickIsActive())        
       beingClicked = true;      

  // If the user was clicking and released the click with the mouse 
  // still hovering the button, beingclicked will be true and the button will be
  // marked as clicked

   else if (beingClicked)
   {
       beingClicked = false;
       actualState = true;
   }

}
else
    beingClicked = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll have a go, too. I suggest a reorganisation of state variables. Get rid of the actual and previous states and just use one `state` for the button appearance, which will be set in our pseudocode snippet. Get rid of `previouslyClicked` (which is equivalent to `state == ONCLICK`) and introduce `pressed` which is true if the button is pressed and false if it isn't:

```
if (CursorIsOnTheButton())  {
    if (LeftClickIsActive())  {
        if (state != ONCLICK) pressed = !pressed;
        state = ONCLICK;
    } else {
        state = (pressed) ? SELECTED : HOVER;
    }
} else {
    state = (pressed) ? SELECTED : NONE;
}
```

The `ONCLICK` state does double duty here; it marks the state "clicking just now" and also ensures that the button isn't flipped on and off during one long mouse-button press. All other states are determined by a simple logic:

```
pressed?      in button?     clicking?      state
------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
true          dontcare      dontcare       SELECTED
false         true          true           ONCLICK
false         true          false          HOVER
false         false         dontcare       NONE
```

This approach has the advantage that you can check the button's depression state with `pressed`, wheras otherwise you'd have to check for the states.

It's still only pseudocode, which means I haven't tested it, of course.

Comment: I think your first line on this table is wrong... shouldnt it be SELECTED?

Comment: Ah, you've cleaned up the table, thanks. I refer to `pressed´ as the new state, which should read "is the button depressed"? `selected` would be a better description, but I avoided it, because thzat is already one of the states. (But `pressed` and `clicking` (as in "clicking right now") should yield `ONCLICK`, no? The original table had it that way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
you have 4 event states to handle, plus the external -force- to 'none'
the following should give you a very good guide as to how to handle the state changes

if state is 'none'
    switch event
    case mousein: 
        set state = 'hover'
        break
    case mousedown: 
        set state = 'onclick'
        break
    case mouseup: 
        set state = 'selected'
        break
    case mouseout:
        break
    default:
        break
    end switch

elseif state is 'hover'
    switch event
    case mouseout: 
        set state = 'none'
        break
    case mousedown: 
        set state = 'onclick'
        break
    case mouseup:
        break
    case mousein: 
        break
    default:
        break
    end switch

elseif state is 'onclick'
    switch event
    case mouseout: 
        set state = 'selected'
        set all other button state values to 'none'
        break
    case mouseup:  
        set state = 'selected'
        set all other button state values to 'none'
        break
    case mousedown: 
        break
    case mousein:
        break
    default:
        break
    end switch

elseif state is 'selected'
    switch event
    case mousein: 
        break
    case mousedown: 
        break
    case mouseup:
        break
    case mouseout:
        break
    default:
        break
    end switch
endif
```